# IIS Disallows Caching for Script/Style with Query Variable

Tags: html, iis, http-headers

I am referencing a script in my ASP.NET MVC application like this:

```
<link href="https://www.example.com/content/resources/styles" rel="stylesheet" />
```

When I do this, the Cache-Control is set to public (which is what I want), allowing the client to cache the content.

However, if I change the URL to this:

```
<link href="https://www.example.com/content/resources/styles?v=123" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then the cache-control: no-cache and pragma: no-cache are added to the response headers - disabling client caching.

Finally, if I change the query variable like this:

```
<link href="https://www.example.com/content/resources/styles?ver=123" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then everything works like it is supposed to again.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is happening because of runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests setting in web.config being set to true.try to set it false.

also, make sure you have the below setting for cashing in iis.

1)open IIS manager, select your site.

2)go to the HTTP response feature.

3)click on the set command header from the action pane. and make sure expire web content is unchecked:

[image]

another way is to allow cache in iis is by using the output caching feature.you can set the query string vale to allow cache for that.

[image]

for more detail refer below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching